# Baire class functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Lemma:
 $F \subseteq R$ is both $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ if and only if $1_F$, the indicator function of F, is Baire-class one.

Lemma:
Let A and B be $F_\sigma$ sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists $A',B'$ $F_\sigma$ set such that $A' \subseteq A$ and $B' \subseteq B, A\bigcup B = A'\bigcup B',$ $A' \bigcap B' = \phi$.
 We can apply the same construction iductively to any finite union of $F_\sigma$.

Now, we use the lemmas to prove the following theorem:

if $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty,a)$ are $F_\sigma$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then f is Baire-class one.

My proof is:

We may assume $0 \leq f \leq 1$. Now, $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is $F_\sigma$ for all $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$. So, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $${E_k}^n = f^{-1}(k2^{-n},(k + 1)2^{-n} + 2^{-2n})$$ \Then there are $G_k^n \subseteq E_k^n F_\sigma-$set such that $G_k^n \bigcap G_l^n = \phi \forall m \neq l$, and $\bigcup_k^n = R$. So, consider the function  $$\phi_n =\sum\limits _{n=2}^{2^n -1}k2^{-n}1_{G_k^n}$$.\Write ${E_k}^n = f^{-1}(k2^{-n},(k + 1)2^{-n})\bigcup ({E_k}^n \bigcap {E_{k+1}}^n)$. If x is in the first part, then $|\phi_n - f(x)| \leq \frac{1+2^{-n}}{2^n}$.If x in the second part, then x is in either $G_k^n $ or $G_{k+1}^n$, then   $|f(x) - \phi_n| \leq \frac{1+2^{-n}}{2^n}$. So, $\phi_n$ converges uniformly and each $\phi_n$  are Baire one , and since the uniform limit of Baire one is Baire one, so f is Baire one function.

My question is why $\phi_n$ is Baire class one function ?